# Start tmux with multiple tabs detached under a user on boot

Tags: boot, bash, tmux

I have the following line in my /etc/rc.local file which starts up tmux under the user "myuser" on boot. But now I want to add in a new tab to this tmux instance. What do I need to modify in this line to have 2 tmux tabs open detached on boot?

```
/bin/su -l myuser -c "/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s mytab -d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either modify the command to add `new-window`:

```
/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s mytab -d \; new-window
```

Or create a `.tmux.conf` with your commands - tmux will run each command when it starts:

```
new-session -smytab -d
new-window
```

And change your command to:

```
/usr/bin/tmux start
```

Or create a separate config with the same and start tmux with:

```
/usr/bin/tmux source /path/to/myconfig
```